# Unix cat to Windows user

Tags: macos, windows-8, unix, cat

I uploaded about 6GB of video in 3 separate files created using the cat command on my Mac, thinking the recipient of those files was a Mac user as well.  It turns out he's using Windows 8.  How can he re-combine that video file on their Windows machine?  He tried the Windows copy command, but the resulting file wouldn't open.

Comment: Were you using `cat` or `nc`?

Comment: I used cat, not nc.

Comment: FWIW, I zipped the video file before using cat to split it into 3 separate files.  My Windows user can't open the zip file after using Windows copy to re-combine the three segments.

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure myself then. Has the Windows user tried installing `cygwin`?

Comment: `cat` concatenates files: I don't see how you can use it for splitting. If you used the `split` command then the Windows `copy` command can re-combine them, as in `copy /b fileA+fileB+fileC fileABC`.

Comment: Whoops, you're correct -- I did use split, and told him to use cat thinking he was a Mac user.  He tried copy, but without the /b.  I'll have him try it with the binary option.  Thanks!

Comment: `copy /b` didn't work.  Perhaps the user did something wrong, or maybe I used some incompatible flag with my `split` command?  I'm going to send him the files on DVD this time, but if anyone has any further insights, feel free to share for the next person who wants to share files from Mac/*nix to Windows in this manner.  Thanks!